# Rails create method to post object not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

I'm new to working with rails. I created a article posting form and when I click the post button it brings me to the articles page but it's not posting what I typed.

`routes.rb`:

```
get 'articles/new' => 'articles#new'
post 'articles' => 'articles#create'
```

`articles_controller.rb`:

```
 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @articles = Article.all
      end

      def new
        @article = Article.new
      end

      def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        if @article.save
          redirect_to '/articles'
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      private

      def article_params
        params.required(:article).permit(:content)
      end
    end

`articles/new.html.erb`:

    <div class="create">
  <div class="container-fluid">


    <%= form_for @article do |t| %>
        <%= t.text_field :title, :placeholder => 'Title', :class => 'article_title'  %>
        <%= t.text_area :body, :placeholder => 'Article', :class => 'article_body' %>
        <%= t.submit 'Post', :class => 'btn-btn-article' %>
<% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

***Server log***:

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 00:43:30 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"c49EXOKfsDP6l2xuquvmUncgTAvXIXpylgx5qK+LvCSrPFvuS37zgR9Cv/BDVwMkCFSYcaWbM+3+qpZazQby8g==", "article"=>{"title"=>"Test", "body"=>"Tsting"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
Unpermitted parameters: title, body
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `articles` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-10-29 04:43:30', '2015-10-29 04:43:30')
  [1m[36m (11.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 11.3ms)


Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 00:43:30 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Rendered articles/index.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 31.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 00:51:17 -0400
Processing by HomeController#home as HTML
  Rendered home/home.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 30.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 00:51:21 -0400
Processing by HomeController#home as HTML
  Rendered home/home.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 29.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 00:51:22 -0400
Processing by HomeController#home as HTML
  Rendered home/home.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 94.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/articles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-29 00:51:29 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#new as HTML
  Rendered articles/new.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 86ms (Views: 85.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Sorry about the articles controller code it wouldn't format right.

Comment: Could you please show your form where you have the post button?

Comment: Can you update the question with the form code and the log generated in the server?

Comment: you really need to start posting more acceptable questions, that's two in a row.

Comment: Checking the log is your best bet in this case. In your server log you should be able to see what's going on with your request.

Comment: I made it look right sorry about that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your server log is telling you the problem:

```
Unpermitted parameters: title, body
```

You have to whitelist your `title` and `body` attributes as Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted.

Change:

```
  def article_params
    params.required(:article).permit(:content)
  end
```

To:

```
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
```

Also, take a look at the official Rails documentation for [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

#### Update

I would suggest you to use [RESTful route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) in your `routes` file:

```
resources :articles
```

Then, you will have this route:

```
articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
```

Then, in your controller's create action, you can use `articles_path`:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Remove the **d** in `required` :)

Comment: I changed it but it still didn't post to the index page?

Comment: it's not supposed to post to the index page, it's supposed to post to the create action.

Comment: Does your model have a `content ` column too? then permit that too. Also, change `required` to `require`. `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :content)` see if that fixes the issue. Otherwise, post the server log again in your question section as an update.

Comment: try using route helper `redirect_to articles_path`

Comment: is the route supposed to look like this:
get 'articles/articles' => 'article#index'

Comment: It should be: `get 'articles' => 'article#index'` if you don't want to go for the RESTful resource.

Comment: I have the resource in the routes file

Comment: I tried a post again and it gave me this error message: 
uninitialized constant ArticleController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93641/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-taylor-gagne).

Answer (score 1):

> Unpermitted parameters: title, body

You should change your `article_params` to below

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Comment: I changed it but it still didn't post to the index page?

Answer (score 1):

It says in your log -

```
Unpermitted parameters: title, body
```

Change your `article_params` method to

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :content)
end
```